# How to get tagged photo from instagram?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, instagram

I got instagram photo by below code but i found that the photo that i got isnt what i want. Anyone can help me on this?

```
<div class="instafeed"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".instafeed").instagram({
        get: 'tagged',
            tagName: 'animals',
        clientId: 'xxx',
        image_size: 'thumbnail',
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm just getting instructions from http://instafeedjs.com/.)

Make sure you're including Instafeed.js on your page.

```
<script src="path/to/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<!--Try using id instead of class-->
<div id="instafeed"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Instafeed({ // call `new Instafeed` here
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'animals',
        clientId: 'xxx',
        image_size: 'thumbnail',
    }).run(); // Call run after initialization
</script>
```